# Why is the Storage Account is not listed in the function app?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am deploying resources to azure using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.*.Fluent API's. The resources being deployed are {`Resource Group`, `Storage Account`, `App Service Plan`, `Function App`}, in order.

I'm curious why my Storage Account is not being assigned to my Function App

```cs
//Create Resource Group
Logger.Info($"Checking for Resource Group: {ResourceGroupName}");
resourceGroup = (await azure.ResourceGroups.ListAsync()).FirstOrDefault(rg => rg.Name == ResourceGroupName);
if (resourceGroup != null)
{
    Logger.Info($"\tFound: {resourceGroup.Name}");
}
else
{
    Logger.Info($"\tNot found. Provisioning resource on Azure...");
    resourceGroup = azure.ResourceGroups.Define(ResourceGroupName).WithRegion(Region.USCentral).Create();
    Logger.Info(
        await azure.ResourceGroups.ContainAsync(ResourceGroupName)
        ? $"\t{ResourceGroupName} Created"
        : $"\tFailed to create Resource Group: {ResourceGroupName}."
    );
}


//Create Storage Account
Logger.Info($"Checking for storage account: {StorageAccountName} in resource group: {ResourceGroupName}");
storageAccount = (await azure.StorageAccounts.ListByResourceGroupAsync(ResourceGroupName))
        .FirstOrDefault(sa => sa.Name == StorageAccountName);
if (storageAccount != null)
{         
    Logger.Info($"\tFound: {storageAccount.Name}");              
}
else
{
    Logger.Info($"\tNot found. Provisioning resource on Azure...");
    storageAccount = await azure.StorageAccounts.Define(StorageAccountName)
        .WithRegion(Region.USCentral)
        .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
        .WithBlobEncryption()
        .WithGeneralPurposeAccountKindV2()
        .WithFileEncryption()
        .WithOnlyHttpsTraffic()
        .WithSku(StorageAccountSkuType.Standard_LRS)
        .WithHnsEnabled(true)
        .CreateAsync();

    Logger.Info(
        (await azure.StorageAccounts.ListByResourceGroupAsync(ResourceGroupName)).Any(x => x.Name == StorageAccountName)
        ? $"\tStorage Account: {StorageAccountName} Created Successfully"
        : $"\tFailed to create Storage Account: {StorageAccountName}."
    );
}


//Create App Service Plan
Logger.Info($"Checking for App Service Plan: {AppServicePlanName} in resource group: {ResourceGroupName}");
appServicePlan = (await azure.AppServices.AppServicePlans.ListByResourceGroupAsync(ResourceGroupName))
        .FirstOrDefault(asp => asp.Name == AppServicePlanName);
if (appServicePlan != null)
{  
    Logger.Info($"\tFound: {appServicePlan.Name}");
}
else
{
    Logger.Info($"\tNot found. Provisioning resource on Azure...");
    appServicePlan = await azure.AppServices.AppServicePlans
    .Define(AppServicePlanName)
    .WithRegion(Region.USCentral)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
    .WithConsumptionPricingTier()
    .CreateAsync();

    Logger.Info(
        ((await azure.AppServices.AppServicePlans.ListByResourceGroupAsync(ResourceGroupName)).Any(x => x.Name == AppServicePlanName))
        ? $"\tApp Service Plan: {AppServicePlanName} Created Successfully"
        : $"\tFailed to create App Service Plan: {AppServicePlanName}."
    );
}

//Create Function App
Logger.Info($"Checking for Function App: {FunctionAppName} in resource group: {ResourceGroupName}");
functionApp = (await azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.ListByResourceGroupAsync(ResourceGroupName)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == FunctionAppName);
if (functionApp != null)
{
    Logger.Info($"\tFound: {functionApp.Name}");
}
else
{
    Logger.Info($"\tNot found. Provisioning resource on Azure...");
    functionApp = await azure.AppServices.FunctionApps
        .Define(FunctionAppName)
        .WithExistingAppServicePlan(appServicePlan)
        .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
        .WithExistingStorageAccount(storageAccount)
        .WithRuntimeVersion("~3")
        .WithHttpsOnly(true)
        .WithWebSocketsEnabled(true)
        .WithPlatformArchitecture(PlatformArchitecture.X64)
        .WithSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity()
        .CreateAsync();

    Logger.Info(
        ((await azure.AppServices.FunctionApps.ListByResourceGroupAsync(ResourceGroupName)).Any(x => x.Name == FunctionAppName))
        ? $"\tFunction app: {FunctionAppName} Created Successfully"
        : $"\tFailed to create Function App: {FunctionAppName}."
    );
}
Logger.Info("\n");
```

When building the function app, I am specifying `.WithExistingStorageAccount(storageAccount)`, which I believe adds the storage account to the function app.

Although, when I checked the returned value, `functionApp.StorageAccount` is `null`. I logged into the portal and checked storage account value in the function app's the deployment template, and found that the azureStorageAccounts collection is also empty.

Answer (score 0):

The resource group actually *is* being added to the azure function - but not as a part of the ARM template itself.

The storage account that is added using `.WithExistingStorageAccount(storageAccount)` gets added as a key-value-pair to the Application Settings.

The `azureStorageAccounts` property is a property of another resource ,`Microsoft.Web/sites/config`, which has a dependency on the function app.